# Returning a rank value based on the index in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is sorted based on DateID.
The goal is to return a rank value based on the index.
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
Index   Name   DateID
0        Sam     4  
1        Sally   3   
2        Samuel  2  
3        Sean    1
```

There desired output should be:

```
Index   Name   DateID   Rank
0        Sam     4        1
1        Sally   3        2
2        Samuel  2        3
3        Sean    1        4
```

Which is solely based on the index.

Comment: based on the index how? is it as simple as `index + 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's as simple as `index + 1` I would just do:

```
df['rank'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.name + 1, axis=1)
```

Head slapper:
as Rho points out, indices act like arrays too. (I thought they behaved more like lists).

So...`df['rank'] = df.index + 1` is probably a lot easier and maybe even faster.

Comment: An alternative: `df['rank'] = df.index + 1`